# Getting type echo is not known when installing cassandra on debian

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cassandra, vagrant

I have a vagrant box up running hashicorps' precise 64 (which is ubuntu I believe). I am installing kong. I have installed kong but now need to install cassandra since kong uses that as a data center. I am following this guide: 
http://cassandra.apache.org/download/
I couldn't find the cassandra.sources.list file inside the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory so I created that file and inserted the following:

```
echo "deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 22x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
```

but when I update the repository by `sudo apt-get update`, I get the following error:  `Type 'echo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list`

Any ideas? Im compeltely new to debian and linux based OS's.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have to copy the line in your file, it is a command that you execute. so directly execute the command from your bash system and it will update the right file for you

```
$ echo "deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 22x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
```

If you really want to create and update the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list` file, you just need to add the line as

```
deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 22x main
```

After this you can safely run the update to install cassandra

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install cassandra
```